# Get language name from windows locale code

Tags: android, locale, nslocale

I have an integer language code looking like this '1031' that needs to be translated to a string like 'German'.

On iOS it's implemented like so

`locale` = [localeIdentifier(fromWindowsLocaleCode:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1412710-localeidentifier)

`language = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.languageCode, value: locale.languageCode)`

Is there anything built in for this?

Backup plan is to parse this [[MS-LCID]: Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID) Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale . Try using Locale.Builder: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.Builder

Comment: I looked at the Locale class and documentation but there is no mention of windows local codes in there.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows official document, it discourages the use of LCID, It is better to use the locale name instead. 
Still, in your case, you can try [GetLocaleInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoa),

```
wchar_t buffer[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];    
GetLocaleInfo(1031, LOCALE_SENGLISHLANGUAGENAME,
            (LPWSTR)&buffer, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
```

from

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

It will give "German" as output in *buffer* array.